# Rebuses around the home

Tags: word, visual, rebus

> [image]

What words are being clued here? Can you find a household object not shown in any of the pictures?

Comment: Is it a 6-letter word? (each pic represent a letter?)

Comment: @Conifers - Probably not: `What words are being clued here?`

Comment: rot13(V guvax gung gur qbyy urnq vf sebz gur YBY frevrf.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. > COCKY (cock - y)
2. > JARRING (jar - ring)
3. > HEADSHOT (head - shot)
4. > KEYNOTE (key - note) (?)
5. > ICONIC (credits to @hdsdv for this one, I was looking for a word ending in ICY, or something to do with red eye, blue sea)
6. > [BONG](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hit%20a%20Bowl) (hit a bowl) or PUNCHBOWL (credits to @hdsdv and @GarethMcCaughan for this idea)

Now

> Picking the third letter of each word yields **CRAYON**

Comment: I believe 5 is rot13(VPBAVP) and 6 is rot13(CHAPUOBJY)

Comment: Last one looks to me more like rot13(chapuobjy). I wonder whether 4 might be rot13(cbfg-vg abgr), punning on rot13("abgr"). Definitely agree about 2 and 3.

Comment: @hdsdv I bet you're right about 5.

Comment: @hdsdv Brilliant, I was not thinking this way.

Comment: Actually, on reflection I like Arnaud's answer for 4 better than mine.

Comment: In fact, I can confirm that all these answers are correct -- I've found the other household object.

Comment: (Not posting it because I expect Arnaud to find it too and clearly he deserves the credit here having found most of the answers.) ... To clarify, rot13(chapuobjy) is the correct answer for 6.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Got it. Thanks for all the help :) and congrats for finding the final answer so fast!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Err, however, my solution for the final answer would work the same with my version of 6... maybe you found something else for the final answer?

Comment: no, I got the same solution as you, I just screwed up by rot13(guvaxvat lbhe nafjre jnf OBJY engure guna OBAT) when I said it had to be mine rather than yours, because I'm an idiot.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I see. I wouldn't go that far :)

Comment: This is correct! For #6 the intended answer is the latter one (which doesn't require an extra leap like the other suggested answer).